# AngularJS constants depending on other constants - any established patterns?

Tags: javascript, angular.js

I'd like to be able to define Angular constants in terms of other constants.

It's not possible to inject dependencies into Angular `constant` services.  When I want one of my constants to depend on another of my constants, I use a `provider` service.  This allows my constants to have dependencies (on other constants), but still be used in my `.config` method call.

This sets off my code smell for two reasons.

1. I'm using a full-blown call to `provider` when I'm really just defining a constant.  It's just that some constants are defined in terms of other constants, and I want to be able to use any of these constants in my `.config` call.
2. I'm injecting providers into my `.config` call and then manually calling their `$get` methods.  This seems to just be bypassing some of the tools Angular gives me.  It seems to me if I'm calling `$get` in my own code, it may be a sign that I'm fighting the framework.

Here's some sample code that shows the above in action.  It defines a constant service that's an enumeration type, then it defines another constant service that depends on the enumeration type, and last it calls the `.config` method, injecting the dependent constant service:

```
app.constant('authLevel', {
    Public: "Public",
    Admin: "Admin",
    SuperAdmin: "SuperAdmin"
});


app.provider("routes", function (authLevel) {

    var routes = [
        {
            path: "/",
            controller: "mapsController",
            templateUrl: "templates/mapsView.html",
            navBarLabel: "LEFT_NAV_BAR.MAPS_NAV_LABEL",
            navBarIconClass: "fa-map-marker",
            authLevels: [authLevel.Public, authLevel.Admin, authLevel.SuperAdmin],
        },
        {
            path: "/markers",
            controller: "markersController",
            templateUrl: "templates/markerListView.html",
            navBarLabel: "LEFT_NAV_BAR.TABLE_NAV_LABEL",
            navBarIconClass: "fa-table",
            authLevels: [authLevel.SuperAdmin],
        }
    ];

    this.$get = function () {
        return routes;
    };
});


app.config(function ($routeProvider, routesProvider) {

    var routes = routesProvider.$get();

    for (var i = 0; i < routes.length; i++) {
        var route = routes[i];
        $routeProvider.when(route.path, {
            controller: route.controller,
            templateUrl: route.templateUrl
        });
    }

    $routeProvider.otherwise({ redirectTo: "/" });
});
```

Am I right to have my code smell go off here?

Are there any sort of established patterns for defining Angular constants that use previously defined constants, and can still be used in the `.config` method?

Answer (score 6):

Using an [IIFE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression) seems to be the tidiest way I've found to do it. This allows you to define your constant as a function (that is immediately invoked) that returns your constant object so you can use it as normal, i.e: LABELS.appName

```
.constant('LABELS', (function () {
    var self = {};
    self.appName = 'MyApp';
    self.companyName = 'MyCompany';
    self.appHeader = self.appName + ' | ' + self.companyName;
    return self;
})());//function is immediately invoked here
```

References:

- [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26549264/1485080)
- [Use functions (IIFE) to define AngularJS constants and values](http://michalostruszka.pl/blog/2012/12/23/angular-better-constant-values/)

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! As far as I can tell, this is a pretty good first answer (it's even got a bibiography!)

Comment: IIFEs do let you control scope as you build complex objects.  However, the constant I'm defining depends on a previously defined constant; I would still need a way to pass 'authLevel' into the anonymous function, something more like this: `.constant('routes', (function (authLevel) {...})(?));`  One might think I could say `app.factory('routes', ['authLevel', function (authLevel) { ... }])`, but dependencies defined using the `factory` method can't be used inside `config`.